# cv2.boundingRect returns wrong coordinates

Tags: python, image, opencv, motion-detection

I tried to build a motion tracking system for Atari games in OpenCV so I could use the information for a reinforcement learning algorithm. 
Here's the Code:

```
import gym
import os
import cv2

env = gym.make('Breakout-v0')

def motion_detection(frame1,frame2):
    delta = cv2.absdiff(frame1,frame2)[2:-2, 2:-2]
    delta = cv2.cvtColor(delta,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    cnts, _, _ = cv2.findContours(delta, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    objects = []
    for c in cnts:
        objects.append(cv2.boundingRect(c))
    return objects

observation = env.reset()
f = 0
while True:
    f += 1
    old_observation = observation
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    objects = motion_detection(old_observation,observation)
    for obj in objects:
        x,y,w,h = obj
        cv2.rectangle(observation,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),1)
    cv2.imwrite(os.getcwd()+'/'+str(f)+'.png',observation)
    if done:
        break
```

Now I've got the Problem that the function `cv2.boundingRect()` seems to be returning the wrong coordinates. The Box is always at the side of the Image. 
Why is that and how do I fix it?
[image: An example of what I'm talking about]

Comment: What do you intend it to return?

Comment: If I'm looking at the image correctly, are the green lines on the left side of the image the bounding boxes?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [latest documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga95f5b48d01abc7c2e0732db24689837b)
, the return order for findContours is image, contour, hierarchy.
So your `cnts, _, _ = cv2.findContours` should be `_, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours`.

I don't see any other problems.

Comment: Thanks, That worked. But know the bounding boxes seem to grow with eyery frame, eventually taking up most of the image.

Comment: That would probably be because you're drawing the rectangle to the same image that's being evaluated by your code (in the cv2.rectangle call). You should create a separate variable for visualization.

Comment: yes as stated by @MateusReis create a copy of the original image: img_copy = observation.copy(); now perform all the subsequent operations on img_copy().